# How to add header to autocomplete tabular format data?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, autocomplete, append

I am trying to display data in autocomplete in table format.Just i am left with showing the header which user can not select.

My code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        $(function () {
            $("#<%=txt.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Webservice.asmx/GetDetails") %>',
                        data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        async: false,
                        mustMatch: true,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.split('^')[0],
                                    val: item.split('^')[1]
                                }
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (response) {

                        },
                        failure: function (response) {

                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function (e, i) {
                    $("#<%=hdnC.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);
                    if (i.item.val == "No Records Found") {
                        $("#<%=hdnC.ClientID %>").val(-1);
                        document.getElementById('<%=txt.ClientID%>').value = "";
                        return false;
                    }

                },
                minLength: 0
            }).bind('focus', function () { $(this).autocomplete("search"); })
            .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
                return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a><table><tr><td width='200px'>" + item.label + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.val.split('~')[6] + "</td></tr></table></a>").appendTo(ul);


             };
        });
    }

</script>
```